# change HTA application window size

Tags: hta

is there any way to change the size of an HTA application?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(300,290);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Javascript and VBScript ways to size the HTA on loading, to 1/4 the screen area *(half the height, half the width)* and center it - using `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

function Window_onLoad(){  // resize to quarter of screen area, centered
   window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth/2,screen.availHeight/2);
   window.moveTo(screen.availWidth/4,screen.availHeight/4);
}

window.onload=Window_onLoad;

</SCRIPT>
```

In VBSScript a `Window_onLoad` sub will automatically get called any time the HTA starts up (or is refreshed) :

```
...
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub Window_onLoad
    ' resize to quarter of screen area, centered
    window.resizeTo screen.availWidth/2,screen.availHeight/2
    window.moveTo screen.availWidth/4,screen.availHeight/4
End Sub 

</SCRIPT>

<BODY>
...
```

I've just tested it (Win XP on an old laptop) and there's a quick flicker of the initial larger window before it shrinks to the smaller size, but it's not that bad.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tip.  If the HTA needs to be resized/moved when the hta is opened, then put the resizeTo and moveTo in its own script tag right after the HEAD tag.  Then you won't see the flash that happens as a result of the resize/move.

```
<HTML>  
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript">
      ' Do the window sizing early so user doens't see the window move and resize
      Window.resizeTo 330, 130

      Call CenterWindow

      Sub CenterWindow()
        Dim x, y
        With Window.Screen
          x = (.AvailWidth  - 330 ) \ 2
          y = (.AvailHeight - 130 ) \ 2
        End With
        Window.MoveTo x, y
      End Sub
    </SCRIPT>
....
```

Comment: Thanks but I've just tried that and it didn't work for me. The resize/move doesn't work unless it's after the `<HTA:..` in the <HEAD>, and by then it seems it's too late because I still get the flicker.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the HTA Attribute windowstate to minimize

```
windowstate="minimize"
```

your resize routine will then set the size you want and force the window display.

first set focus to your window:

```
    window.focus()
    window.resizeTo(500,500)
    window.moveTo(screen.availWidth-500,0)
```